# How to use WinMerge with High-DPI Windows setting?

Tags: dpi, winmerge

I was trying to find an alternative for WinMerge to solve my blurry text problem with 150% DPI. Although my question was closed (I consider this mentality unhelpful), but I found the answer so I share it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can continue using WinMerge:

1. Right-click on the program's icon -> Properties -> Compatibility -> check "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings".
2. Choose a bigger font: View -> Select Font...

Note that with Windows 8.1, you can't do this from the start menu, so first open start, find "winmerge" by typing, and then right click and select select "Open File in Location". You will then be able to right click and choose properties in the folder.